# Python find the index of a multi value List?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I can't see the answer for this anywhere but I know it's a stupid question so sorry in advance!!

I have a list like this:

```
fullList = [("a","/a/"),("b","/b/"),("c","/c/"),("d","/d/"),("e","/e/")]
```

If I have the value, lets say c then how do I get it's index for the array?

If I use the index method it's doesn't work:

```
listIndex = fullList.index('c')
```

Any ideas?

Cheers and sorry if a really stupid question...

Comment: If I don't know what the second part is, /c/ ?

Comment: mcquaim, see my edit to my answer. It builds a list of the first parts of the tuples and matches on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need a list comprehension and use `in` operation  :

```
>>> [fullList.index(i) for i in fullList if 'c' in i]
[2]
```

If you just want to check for first index you can use this:

```
>>> [fullList.index(i) for i in fullList if i[0]=='c']
[2]
```

Also note that you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function in your list comprehension that have more performance here , (the order of `index()` is `O(n)`) you can refuse from an extra searching !

```
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(fullList) if j[0]=='c']
[2]

>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(fullList) if 'c' in j]
[2]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone, sorted now!

Answer (score 1):

A list's index() looks for equality on the elements of the list, so you want to provide the item that equals what you're looking for. Specifically, in this case, it would be:

```
listIndex = fullList.index(('c', '/c/'))
```

If you really need to search by the first element of the tuple, you can grab just the first one of each item and do .index on that:

```
listIndex = [ e[0] for e in fullList ].index('c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the index or the full value ? In the second case:

```
>>> found = dict(fullList).get('c')
>>> print found
("c", "/c/")
```